# Finding the maximum and minimum of $V(t) = 2t^2 − 16 t + 40$

Tags: polynomials

The volume of water in a tank, V m3, over a 10 month period is given by the function $V(t) = 2t^2 − 16 t + 40,$ where t is in months and $ t ∈ [0, 10].$

I completed the sure and got $2(t - 4)^2 + 24$ and the turning point was (4, 24). I then did t = 0 so V = 40 and t = 10 and V = 80. But the answer is 8 is minimum and 80 is the maximum.

Comment: Arithmetical error in completing the square, it is $2(t-4)^2+8$.

Comment: as @AndréNicolas said: $2\cdot4^2-16\cdot4+40=8$   $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Please elaborate

Comment: $2t^2 −16t+40 =8$ when $t=4$

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion that t = 4

Comment: By completing the square you express the volume as the sum of two parts - the square part is non-negative and depends on $t$, the other part is constant. The square part is a minimum when it is zero, and it is zero when $t=4$. Since the other part doesn't change, that is also when the whole expression is a minimum.

Comment: I have taken the liberty of changing $(t^2-4)$ to $(t-4)$ which I think was just a typo - when you had $t^2-4$ in the bracket, you wouldn't be able to see $t=4$ as the minimum: perhaps that was your problem ...

Comment: thanks a lot both of you guys

Comment: @Orbit: You seem to be one of the new users who don't know how to accept answers. On this site, if your question has been answered to your satisfaction, you accept it by clicking on the little greyed out hook under the vote counter on the left of every answer. You have 9 questions and zero accepted answers. Please go ahead and look whether some of them maybe have satisfying answers. Every accepted answer will also give you 2 reputation. Once you have 15 reputation you will also be able to up vote answers or comments. You can do this by clicking on the "up arrow" next to an answer or comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First completing the square gives
$$2(t^2-8t+20)=2((t-4)^2-16+20)=2(t-4)^2+8$$

Therefore the minimum is at $t=4$ giving $8$ and the maximum at $t=10$ giving $80$.

Answer (score 1):

Another way If you know differential calculus

$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t} (2t^2 - 16t +40) = 4t -16$$

If we make this equal to zero as it is as a local maximum or minimum $t = \frac{16}{4} = 4$

Putting this back into our original equation

$$2(4)^2-16(4)+40 = 8$$

There are no other local maximums or minimums so check the end points

$$2(0)^2-16(0)+40 = 40$$

$$2(10)^2-16(10)+40 = 80$$

Our minimum is thus $8$ at $t=4$ and the maximum is $80$ at $t=10$

Comment: (+1) But please use brackets behind the $d/dt$ in the first equation. It hurts my eyes :-O.